# Javascript cast/change into Boolean

Tags: javascript

How can I cast/change the following code into a boolean:

```
var $templateContext = $(templateHTML);
var ePopup = $templateContext.data('e-popup');
if (typeof ePopup === 'undefined') {
   ePopup = 'yes';
} // If not set, give it the value of 'yes'.
```

And how can I do this line differently?

```
if (ePopup === 'no' || ePopup === 'false' || !ePopup) {
    okayToLaunchPopup = false;
}
```

And this cast to boolean ?

```
if (typeof ePopup === 'undefined') {
   ePopup = 'yes';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `okayToLaunchPopup = !(ePopup === 'no' || ePopup === 'false' || !ePopup)`

Comment: you can use !! to convert a variable to boolean (!!var)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this can help you.

```
okayToLaunchPopup = ePopup = typeof ePopup === 'undefined' ? true: false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply done . This is will only execute , when epopup have any specific value ,if value is null or undefined it is not going to execute .

```
if (typeof ePopup) {  
   ePopup = 'yes';
}
```

same with others too.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to cast things to boolean in javascript is to use the !! (not not). For instance:

const myString = 'Some words';
console.log(!!myString) // true;

const emptyString = '';
console.log(!!myString) // false;